# If positive reals $a$ and $b$ satisfy $a\sqrt{a}+b\sqrt{b}=183, a\sqrt{b}+b\sqrt{a}=182$, find $\frac{9}{5}(a+b)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, factoring

Question from Math Olympiad:

> Suppose $a, b$ are positive real numbers such that $a\sqrt{a} + b\sqrt {b} = 183$ and $a\sqrt{b} + b\sqrt {a} = 182$. Find $\frac{9}{5}(a+b)$.

My approach:

$a\sqrt{a} + b\sqrt {b} = 183$

$a\sqrt{b} + b\sqrt {a} = 182$

Therefore $(\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b})(a+b) = 365$

I only see two integral possibilities:

$1 \times 365 $  and $5 \times 73 $

And on putting either of them, I am getting $657$ and $131.4$, whereas the answer is an integral $73$.

Please help me with the general method to go about the same.

[image]

This is the picture from the source.

Comment: In any case, $(\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b})(a+b) = 366$ and not $365$.

Comment: The title does not match the contents of the post. Is it 183 twice, or 183 and 182?

Comment: Now the title is still wrong, as is presumably the quoted Olympiad question, which caused the misunderstandings in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Let $x=\sqrt a$ and $y=\sqrt b$. You know that
$$x^3+y^3=183$$
and
$$xy(x+y)=182.$$
Since
$$x^3+3xy(x+y)+y^3=(x+y)^3,$$
you can use this to find $x+y$; see if you can use this to find $\frac 95(x^2+y^2).$

Comment: +1 Nice one! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :** If you make the difference of the two equations, you get
$$(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})(a-b)=0$$

Probably you can conclude.

Comment: @DestinyFindsYou $183-183=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\sqrt a=x,\sqrt b=y$

$$\implies\dfrac{183}{182}=\dfrac{x^3+y^3}{xy(x+y)}$$

As $x+y\ne0,$  $$182 x^2-365xy+182y^2=0\implies\dfrac xy=\dfrac{13}{14}\text{ or }\dfrac{14}{13}$$

If $\dfrac xy=\dfrac{13}{14},\dfrac x{13}=\dfrac y{14}=z$(say)

So, we have $$182=z^3(13\cdot14)(13+14)\implies z^3=?$$

As $z$ is real, $z=\sqrt[3]{\dfrac1{27}}=\dfrac13\implies x=?,y=?$

We need $$\dfrac{9(a+b)}5=\dfrac{9(x^2+y^2)}5=?$$

Comment: @Phymathechem, How about this?